# Replacing all but specific elements using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

Using regular expressions in Python, I am trying to remove all XML-type elements in a string, except those containing QUOTE, eg `<QUOTE>`, `</QUOTE>` or `<QUOTE A="B">` should remain, but others such as `<EXAMPLE>` or `<TEST A="B">` should be removed. I've created this, which replaces all elements but can't work out the not part:

```
re.sub(r'</?[\w= \-"]+>', '', s)
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Can you give us an example of an XML tag that you _wouldn't_ want to remove?

Comment: Done. Forgot the backticks :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe a negative lookahead assertion will do what you want:

```
import re

regex = r'<(?!/?QUOTE\b)[^>]+>'

tests = [
    'a plain old string',
    'a string with <SOME> <XML TAGS="stuff">',
    'a string with <QUOTE>, </QUOTE>, and <QUOTE with="data">',
    'a string that has <QUOTEA> tags </QUOTEB>',
]

for i in tests:
    result = re.sub(regex, '', i)
    print('{}\n{}\n'.format(i, result))
```

EDIT: How it works

Lookahead assertions, as the name suggests, "look ahead" in the string being matched, but don't consume the characters they're matching. You can do positive (`(?=...)`) and negative (`(?!...)`) lookaheads. (There are also positive and negative lookbehind assertions.)

So, the regex shown matches `<` for the beginning of a tag, then does a negative lookahead for `QUOTE` with an optional `/` before it (`/?`) and a word boundary behind it (`\b`). If that's matched, the regex does not match, and that tag is ignored. If it's not matched, the regex goes on to eat one or more non-`>` characters, and the closing `>`. I guess you might want to have it eat any whitespace following the tag, too - I didn't do that.

Comment: This solution is the good one. Not hard to find, but anyway +1

Comment: However, ``/?`` must be out of the lookahead assertion

Comment: @eyquem: It does? Why? The code appears to work correctly: both `QUOTE` and `/QUOTE` are ignored.

Comment: Oh you're right: a character ``/`` is matched by ``[^>]`` . I was wandering absent-mindedly among posts

Answer (score 1):

I'd first replace QUOTE with some weird symbol that doesn't appear in the text, like maybe ^:

```
s = re.sub(r'(</?)QUOTE','\1^',s)
```

Then get rid of the XML tags that don't contain your weird symbol:

```
s = re.sub(r'</?[\w= \-"]+>','',s)
```

Then put the QUOTEs back in:

```
s = re.sub(r'(</?)\^','\1QUOTE',s)
```

EDIT: You can always combine these into one line by composition:

```
s = re.sub(r'(</?)\^','\1QUOTE',re.sub(r'</?[\w= \-"]+>','',re.sub(r'(</?)QUOTE','\1^',s)))
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, but is it possible in one regex?

Comment: I don't think so... Regexps don't actually have a negation operator.

Answer (score 0):

rmalouf's approach should work.

Here is a potential one-liner.

```
re.sub(r'<[/]?[^Q][^U][^O][^T][^E][^>]*>', '', s)
```

[/]? should match the /, when it is present.

[^>]*> matches everything else inside the tag, and the tag closer.

If you are expecting no other tags that start with Q, you can shorten it further:

```
re.sub(r'<[/]?[^Q][^>]*>', '', s)
```

Comment: That matches the element I DO want to keep though :) Can this be modified to remove all elements BUT those with QUOTE in them?

Comment: Yes sorry, I've edited the post!  I hate it when I read the exact OPPOSITE of what something says. :)

Comment: Your first regexp will only match tags with at least 5 characters.

Comment: I think you're right :( For some reason it's also removing </QUOTE> which I can't fathom.

Comment: [/]? is matching the empty string between < and /, [^Q] is matching the /, [^U] is matching the Q, and so on.

Comment: Alas.  I think that given the complexity of what the regex would have to be to handle these quirks, it would be faster and more intuitive to use rmalouf's approach.