# reverse replace all using caracter and word

Tags: regex

I found this pattern in another post:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^xyz]"); s.replaceAll(p.pattern(), "-");
```

It allow to replace all of characters except x, y and z

How can we adapt it to add a word in the reverse replace all ? For exemple, I'd like to keep xyz and the word dog

exemple:

"abcxyzabcxyzdfrdogdzx" -- > "xyzxyzdogzx"

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all but specific elements using regex in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423811/replacing-all-but-specific-elements-using-regex-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

For this, you'll need to capture words that you want globally, and join the matches together.

In JS:

```
/([xyz]|dog)/g
```

Breakdown:

- `[xyz]` - any character from the list x, y, z
- `dog` - match `dog` literally
- `([xyz]|dog)` - capture the list, or dog
- `/g` - the global modifier

```js
let string = "abcxyzabcxyzdfrdogdzx",
  regex = /([xyz]|dog)/g,
  whatWeAreLookingFor = string.match(regex).join("");

console.log(whatWeAreLookingFor);
```

Comment: I was thinking in terms of negative look behind that i forgot the simple straight forward matches... brilliant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunatly, it doesn't work for me.

Here is the code I used in Java:

    String s = "${variable1}TITITITffsdfsdfsdfsdffI$dog{variable2}";
    String cleaned = s.replaceAll("([^${}]|^dog)", "-");
    System.out.println(cleaned);
And the result is the following:

${---------}-----------------------$---{---------}

As I'd like to keep $ { } and the word dog, I expect to have the following result:

${---------}-----------------------$dog{---------}

Comment: Use a regex library and do a match rather than a replace. For Java, you may have to start joining after character group 0 (which will be the full match), but a replace is not what I’m doing here. You could probably do this with the Regex class in Java